# Xcode test target build failing

Tags: xcode8

I am using Xcode 8.3.2 for building my framework. My framework project has both xctest and xcuitest target. When i am building my framework target, its building properly but test taget is failing. This is working fine with Xcode 8 version. Following is the error i am getting:
error: cannot parse the debug map for "/Users/chintu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InAppPurchase-cfkrmkjfogyteqhcvlxfujvetrmb/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/InAppPurchaseTests.xctest/InAppPurchaseTests": No such file or directory

Note: I have tried cleaning derived data, restarting xcode again but nothing seems to be working.